# Check date range is not already booked in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working in an online bike booking system. Where the customer can book a bike for particular date-time range. If another customer books the same bike for a particular date-time range, I have to check that bike is already booked or not.
My database table **booking** is like this:

```
 id     bike_id      start_date             end_date
  1       1       2019-05-04 14:30      2019-05-04 15:30
  1       1       2019-05-04 16:30      2019-05-04 18:30
```

Suppose if another customer wants to book a bike for 2019-05-04 17:00 to 2019-05-04 19:30 (i.e. start_date to end_date) then the bike should not be available. Booking should available only if no other previous bookings overlap in requested date-time range.
How to write a MySQL query for this in laravel?

Comment: have you checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245007/laravel-5-check-if-event-date-range-is-not-already-taken)

Comment: Why you are not comparing your input dates to booking dates for that particular bike or better not to display those bikes to be chosen.

Comment: Thanks @Hamelraj It worked :)

Comment: @Raghu plz press up to that link

Answer (score 0):

you can use whereRaw to check a date between two columns

```php
whereRaw('? between start_date and end_date', [date('Y-m-d')])
```

or

```php
where(function ($q) {
  $q->where('start_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'));
  $q->where('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d'));
})
```

Comment: This will not work for comparing date range with two different input dates, like user submitted start & end with database start & end date range.